# R cannot be resolved: Android error

Tags: android

After having read the solutions they dont seem to work, I organised the imports and then deleted import.android.R; and tried to debug the Jetboy game but still the R error remains, can anybody help plz?

Comment: You are missing a lot of context here.

Comment: if you're using eclipse, try cleaning the project and let eclipse rebuild it for you.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, there is an option called "build automatically" that is on by default.

The Android SDK, upon the project build, reads all the XML files and constructs your R file, in the gen folder, according to the information in the XML files. But it will only (re)generate them if the project builds successfully.

You must guaranty a successful build in order to have your R. Any error in the XML file (look for the red X inside each file) will prevent R from being generated.

If you could supply more info, we could help you out better ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that in your project, under the `gen` folder, there is nothing there, meaning Eclipse is failing to create the R file. This usually happens when there is an error in an XML file. So you need to look through the xml files and see where there is an error. Sometimes Eclipse fails to notify you of the error, and it can help to Clean the project in Eclipse, and then close Eclipse, then open it again, and it will then usually catch and notify you of any errors that exist.